# Redirect pdf file to another domain with htaccess file but keep all previous redirect settings

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, redirect

I've been searching for a few hours but all the similar questions that approach the main theme of my problem aren't clear enough.

Right now, I have a .htaccess on my oldwebsite.com with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is working fine.

But I need to include a RewriteRule for a pdf file located on: https://oldwebsite.com/storage/uploads/media/name-1.pdf

Tried so many rules by now but any of them worked.

Can some one give me a hint?

Comment: "I need to include a RewriteRule for a pdf" - And do what exactly? "Tried so many rules" - like what? And _where_? And how did it "not work"?

Comment: It looks like you may have tried to edit this while logged into a different account.  That isn't going to work.  Edits that substantially change a post get rejected as conflicting with the author's intent.  To edit your own posts, make sure you log into the same account from which you originally posted.